# Cannot install LAMP server in UBUNTU

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

I am new using Ubuntu. Basically I want to set the LAMP package in order to test PHP locally. So I installed tasksel then I executed in the terminal.

```
sudo tasksel
```

Which promps a list of servers I can install. I move the cursor to LAMP Server option, hits enter and returns to the command line. Like if I had pressed EXIT.

What am I missing? Can someone experienced help me install LAMP even if it is on another way? I have Ubuntu 13, by the way. I have been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: Try this tutorial http://wiki.workassis.com/ubuntu-install-lamp-using-tasksel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with.

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 1):

To install apache, open terminal and type in these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

to test if apache is working use this simple script:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

and browse to : `http://<you'r ip address>`

to install mysql open the terminal and write this:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

Once you have installed MySQL, we should activate it with this command:

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

Finish up by running the MySQL set up script:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

The prompt will ask you for your current root password.

Type it in.

```
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
OK, successfully used password, moving on...
```

Now, its time to install PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

That's it! restart apache to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found a more simple way, but thanks anyway, I am learning from this.

Answer (score 0):

Change user to root

```
sudo su root
```

update the repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install LAMP packages by,

```
apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

This three simple step is enough to install LAMP.

Courtasy: [iGyan: Install LAMP with PHPmyadmin in linux](http://igyan.org/how-to/install-lamp-with-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install LAMP stack in Ubuntu with one command lines:

`apache2 mysql-server mysql-client libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-cli php5-gd phpmyadmin apache2-utils`